# align text and images within a div

Tags: html, css

I have this div and in it I have a `<h1>` element and two social media icons. I want to line them up side by side with the the `h1` vertically centered with the icons. I want this to be centered in its div. Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/iamgonge/pen/zREoJw).

```css
.social-section {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
}

.social-section>h1,
.social-section>div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.social-section>h1 {
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-section">
  <h2>Follow us </h2>
  <a href src="/"><img src="https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/s-vbmsnb3b18/product_images/uploaded_images/fb-logo.png" /></a>
  <a href src="/"><img src="https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/s-vbmsnb3b18/product_images/uploaded_images/instagram.png" /></a>
</div>
```

What am I missing here? Is there some easy method to follow? I seem to always have trouble lining up elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make use of ***[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)***

- `display:flex` will align the flex items(child elements) side by side.
- `align-items: center` align items vertically center
- `justify-content: center` align items horizontally center

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.social-section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-section">
  <h2>Follow us </h2>
  <a href src="/"><img src="https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/s-vbmsnb3b18/product_images/uploaded_images/fb-logo.png" /></a>
  <a href src="/"><img src="https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/s-vbmsnb3b18/product_images/uploaded_images/instagram.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: But beware that flex is not supported by older browsers so you should fallback to some `display:table` hack.

Answer (score 1):

Just set elements in [`display:inline-block`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)

`vertical-align:middle` provide to center vertically your elements

```css
.social-section
{
  text-align:center;
}

.social-section > *{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-section">
  <h2>Follow us </h2>
  <a href src="/"><img src="https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/s-vbmsnb3b18/product_images/uploaded_images/fb-logo.png" /></a>
  <a href src="/"><img src="https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/s-vbmsnb3b18/product_images/uploaded_images/instagram.png" /></a>
</div>
```